# How do I write the problematic code to avoid getting the error?

Tags: django, html

I get the error after typing the code in the models.py field after determining the application name in urls.py

No problem before defining the application name.

Django==2.2

Python==3.x

**Blog/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from Home.views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', HomeView),
    re_path(r'^Post/', include('Post.urls')),
]
```

**Post/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import *

AppName = 'Post'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^Index/$', PostIndex, name='Index'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', PostDetail, name='Detail'),
    re_path(r'^Create/$', PostCreate, name='Create'),
    re_path(r'^Update/$', PostUpdate, name='Update'),
    re_path(r'^Delete/$', PostDelete, name='Delete'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

    class Post(models.Model):
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        Content = models.TextField()
        PublishingDate = models.DateTimeField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.Title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('Post:Detail', kwargs={'id':self.id})
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% for Post in Posts %}
        {{ Post.id }}<br>
        <a href="{{ Post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ Post.Title }}</a><br>
        {{ Post.Content }}<br>
        {{ Post.PublishingDate }}<br>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

I am not receiving an error without defining the application name in the models.py field. There is an error in code editing in the models.py field.

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):

seamless code => return reverse('Detail', kwargs={'id':self.id})
problematic code => return reverse('Post:Detail', kwargs={'id':self.id})
```

How do I write the problematic code to avoid getting the error?

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: File "/root/Belgeler/Python/Django/Alıştırmalar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 86, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'Post' is not a registered namespace

Comment: When you use ```Post:Detail```, ```Post``` is the namespace, you have to define the namespace in your main urls file. Add your main urls file code to your question so I can give you an answer.

Comment: I added above by editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a namespace to your Post urls:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from Home.views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', HomeView),
    re_path(r'^Post/', include('Post.urls', namespace='Post')),
]
```

Comment: 'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

Comment: I solved the problem.
**Post/urls.py**  in the field of app_name, the problem was corrected.

**true =>** app_name = 'Post'


**false =>** AppName = 'Post'

 Thank You